# Splitting an RACSignal to eliminate state

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

I'm using ReactiveCocoa to update a `UILabel` whilst a `UIProgressView` counts down:

```
NSInteger percentRemaining = ...;
self.progressView.progress = percentRemaining / 100.0;

__block NSInteger count = [self.count];

[[[RACSignal interval:0.05 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
    take: percentRemaining]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        count++;
        self.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
        self.progressView.progress = self.progressView.progress - 0.01;
    } completed:^{
        // Move along...
    }];
```

This works well enough but, I'm not particularly happy with either the `count` variable or with reading the value of `self.progressView.progress` in order to decrement it.

I feel like I should be able to spit the signal and bind the properties directly using the `RAC` macro. Something like:

```
RACSignal *baseSignal = [[RACSignal interval:0.05 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
                            take: percentRemaining]

RAC(self, countLabel.text) = [baseSignal
                                  map: ...
                                  ...

RAC(self, progressView.progress) = [baseSignal
                                        map: ...
                                        ...
```

The `...`s reveal where I'm stuck. I can't quite get my head around how to compose the `RACSignal` such that I don't need to rely on a state variable.

Additionally I'm not sure where/how to inject the `// Move along...` side effect I need when the stream completes.

I'm sure both are simple enough once you're thinking the right way but, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When in doubt, check out
[RACSignal+Operations.h](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h)
and
[RACStream.h](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h),
because there's bound to be an operator for what you want to do. In this case,
the basic missing piece is
[-scanWithStart:reduce:](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/f9bc1fd2c58e0c5f9096a1c42d3e51d9c912d4e0/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h#L226-L254).

First of all, though, let's look at the `baseSignal`. The logic will stay
basically the same, except that we should publish [a
connection](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACMulticastConnection.h)
for it:

```
RACMulticastConnection *timer = [[[RACSignal
    interval:0.05 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
    take:percentRemaining]
    publish];
```

This is so that we can share a single timer between all of the dependent
signals. Although the `baseSignal` you provided would also work, that'll
recreate a timer for each subscriber (including dependent signals), which might
lead to tiny variances in their firing.

Now, we can use `-scanWithStart:reduce:` to increment the `countLabel`
*and* decrement the `progressView`. This operator takes previous results and the
current value, and lets us transform or combine them however we want.

In our case, though, we just want to ignore the current value (the `NSDate` sent
by `+interval:`), so we can just manipulate the previous one:

```
RAC(self.countLabel, text) = [[[timer.signal
    scanWithStart:@0 reduce:^(NSNumber *previous, id _) {
        return @(previous.unsignedIntegerValue + 1);
    }]
    startWith:@0]
    map:^(NSNumber *count) {
        return count.stringValue;
    }];

RAC(self.progressView, progress) = [[[timer.signal
    scanWithStart:@(percentRemaining) reduce:^(NSNumber *previous, id _) {
        return @(previous.unsignedIntegerValue - 1);
    }]
    startWith:@(percentRemaining)]
    map:^(NSNumber *percent) {
        return @(percent.unsignedIntegerValue / 100.0);
    }];
```

The `-startWith:` operators in the above may seem redundant, but this is
necessary to ensure that `text` and `progress` are set before `timer.signal` has
sent anything.

Then, we'll just use a normal subscription for completion. It's entirely
possible that these side effects could be turned into signals as well, but it's
hard to know without seeing the code:

```
[timer.signal subscribeCompleted:^{
    // Move along...
}];
```

Finally, because we used a `RACMulticastConnection` above, nothing will actually
fire yet. Connections have to be manually started:

```
[timer connect];
```

This connects *all* of the above subscriptions, and kicks off the timer, so the
values begin flowing to the properties.

---

Now, this is obviously more code than the imperative equivalent, so one might
ask why it's worthwhile. There are several benefits:

1. The value calculations are now **thread-safe**, because they don't depend on side
   effects. If you need to implement something more expensive, it's extremely easy
   to move the important work to a background thread.
2. Similarly, the value calculations are **independent** of each other. They
   can be easily parallelized if this ever becomes valuable.
3. All of the logic is now **local to the bindings**. You don't have to wonder
   where changes are coming from or worry about the ordering (e.g., between
   initialization and updating), because it's all in one place and can be read
   top-down.
4. The values can be calculated **without any reference to a view**. For
   example, in [Model-View-ViewModel](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveViewModel#model-view-viewmodel),
   the count and progress would actually be determined in a [view
   model](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveViewModel#whats-in-a-view-model),
   and then the view layer is just a set of dumb bindings.
5. The changing values flow from **only one input**. If you suddenly need to
   incorporate another input source (e.g., real progress instead of a timer),
   there's only one place you need to change.

Basically, this is a classic example of imperative vs. functional programming.

Although imperative code can start off less complex, it grows in complexity
*exponentially*. Functional code (and especially functional reactive code) may
start off more complex, but then its complexity grows *linearly* — it's much
easier to manage as the application grows.

Comment: Man, you're a beast! Beastly good! This post would worth a Stellar Answer badge if we were a bigger community.

Comment: What @allprog said! Wow. Thanks — really couldn't ask for a better explanation.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers Care to elaborate a bit your 'imperative code grows exponentially and FRP code grows linearly' statement? Seems like a… bold claim; I'm curious to hear the thinking behind it.

Comment: @ipmcc Every additional bit of state doubles the number of _possible states_ for your application to be in at any given moment. If you eliminate state, the complexity of the code is reduced to (more or less) just the potential for logic errors.