# ReactiveCocoa: eliminate state in subscribeNext: block

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have the following code in my VC:

```
[RACObserve(self.viewModel, searchMode) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *value) {
    @strongify(self);
    BOOL isSearchMode = [value boolValue];
    self.searchBarView.hidden = !isSearchMode;
    if (isSearchMode) {
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
        self.yContentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y;
        [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, 0) animated:NO];
    } else {
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, self.yContentOffset) animated:NO];
    }
}];
```

where `yContentOffset` is VC's property which I am trying to remove. (It saves content offset before entering search mode and restores it after).

I've tried `[RACSignal if: then: else:]` but did not managed to get it completely.

Comment: What does your +if:then:else: attempt look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got three distinct values that need to change when `self.viewModel.searchMode` does, so I think the first thing you want to do is [split the signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852844/splitting-an-racsignal-to-eliminate-state?rq=1) and take each of them separately.

```
RACSignal * searchModeSig = [[RACObserve(self.viewModel, searchMode) distinctUntilChanged] 
                                 publish] 
                             signal];
```

The `hidden` status is simple:

```
RAC(self.searchBarView, hidden) = [searchModeSig not];
```

I used [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/f9bc1fd2c58e0c5f9096a1c42d3e51d9c912d4e0/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L312) above because your signal to the collection view's y offset seems to be "0 if the `searchMode` is `YES`, else the last non-zero value". If the `searchMode` signal's value were to be `YES` or `NO` in succession, you'd also end up with a duplication in the stream of offset values, which would screw up using `replayLast` to get the value you want. `distinctUntilChanged` only passes along values that represent a transition from `YES` to `NO` or vice-versa.

```
RAC(self.collectionView, contentOffset) = 
    [RACSignal if:searchModeSig
             then:[RACSignal return:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, 0)]
             else:[RACObserve(self.collectionView, contentOffset) replayLast]];
```

This should insert the 0 `y` value into the stream whenever `searchMode` *transitions* to `YES`, and take the previous value (which, of course, could have been updated from elsewhere) whenever it transitions to `NO`.

For the first responder status of the search bar, it seems reasonable to do that with `subscribeNext:`, but you could also do this:

```
RAC(self.searchBar, DLShouldBeFirstResponder) = searchModeSig;
```

Where you've turned the `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder` calls into a pseudo-property like so:

```
@interface UIView (DLFirstResponderProp)

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL DLShouldBeFirstResponder;

@end


@implementation UIView (DLFirstResponderProp)

- (void)setDLShouldBeFirstResponder:(BOOL)shouldBe
{
    if( shouldBe ){
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (BOOL)DLShouldBeFirstResponder
{
    return [self isFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

It might also be that [lifting](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/NSObject%2BRACLifting.h) would be the "official" way to go from signal to imperative call, but I'm not sure how/if that works with parameterless methods.

Comment: I'd be very happy to hear critique of this; I only started trying to figure out RAC myself this weekend.

Comment: That's a lot of knowledge for the weekend) Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did it work? Great! (Scheme was one of the first languages I learned, so I had a good start for the  "functional" part of FRP.)